# How to order by FIELD with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
  t.type,
  SUM( t.external_account )
FROM
  u_contracts c,
  u_data u,
  u_transactions t
WHERE
  c.user_id = u.id
  AND t.contract_id = c.id
  AND t.nulled =0
  AND DATE (c.init_date) < DATE (u.dead)
  AND u.dead IS NOT NULL
  AND t.type != 'repay'
GROUP BY
  t.type;
```

Now this gives me the desired result, but now I want to add ORDER BY to it, but by specific field name like:

```
ORDER BY FIELD( t.type, 'type1', 'type2', ... )
```

But I can't insert that into the query. When I try like this:

```
SELECT
  t.type,
  SUM( t.external_account )
FROM
  u_contracts c,
  u_data u,
  u_transactions t
WHERE
  c.user_id = u.id
  AND t.contract_id = c.id
  AND t.nulled =0
  AND DATE (c.init_date) < DATE (u.dead)
  AND u.dead IS NOT NULL
  AND t.type != 'repay'
ORDER BY
  FIELD( t.type, 'initial', 'commision', 'overpay', 'penalty', 'penalty2' )
GROUP BY
  t.type;
```

It gives my sql error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY t.type' at line 17
```

What is the proper way in doing this?

Comment: Change your query into this: `SELECT t.type, SUM( t.external_account ) FROM u_contracts c, u_data u, u_transactions t WHERE c.user_id = u.id  AND t.contract_id = c.id  AND t.nulled =0 AND DATE (c.init_date) < DATE (u.dead) AND u.dead IS NOT NULL  AND t.type != 'repay' GROUP BY t.type ORDER BY FIELD( t.type, 'initial',  'commision', 'overpay', 'penalty', 'penalty2' );`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have the wrong order for `group by` and `order by`;

```
...
ORDER BY
  FIELD( t.type, 'initial', 'commision', 'overpay', 'penalty', 'penalty2' )
GROUP BY
  t.type;
```

Should be:

```
...
GROUP BY
  t.type
ORDER BY
  FIELD( t.type, 'initial', 'commision', 'overpay', 'penalty', 'penalty2' );
```